# Can´t understand Java basics

Tags: java, methods

I am starting to learn Java and I am struggling trying to understand why in this situation, the account money doesn't change to 5.

Trying with code I have realized that inside the method `manipulate()` the money of c1 actually changes but when returns to the main, it just increases and doesn't get the value of c2 (guess it is something about memory directions).

I am little familiarized with C and I understand it must be something like using a parameter with or without pointer but as this is OOP, I cant understand it. Could someone explain me easily?

```
public class Account {
    private int money;
    
    public Account(int money){
        this.money=money;
    }
    
    public static void manipulate(Account c1){
        c1.add(120);
        Account c2 = new Account(5);
        c1 = c2;
    }
    
    public void add(int money){
        this.money += money;
    }
    
    public int actual_money(){
        return this.money;
    }
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        
      Account c1 = new Account(100);

      manipulate(c1);
      
      System.out.println("Money = " + c1.actual_money()); //prints 220
    }
}
```

Comment: `c1 = c2` has no effect because you are overwriting a local parameter. Java is not C or C# in this regard and can't overwrite the original reference from within the method.

Comment: @akarnokd, c# behaves exactly the same way as java by default, but you can pass the parameter by reference using ref keyword

Comment: @VladimirEfimenko I know but didn't want to confuse the OP with syntax not existing in Java.

Comment: It has nothing to do with OOP, this is how parameters are passed to the methods, the c1 is a copy of a reference you pass to the method

Comment: And C would behave the same if you passed an Account pointer to a function and then reassigned the pointer to point to a different Account struct within the function. The reason in all three cases is that you are passing a pointer (or a reference) by *value* and assigning a different value to the parameter has no effect on the caller.

Comment: The title of your Question here should be a summary of your specific technical issue.